# How can I login with an email created inside cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, email

I created  email inside cpanel. `info@jegeachi.com`. I do some configuration by googling.But when I try to login it says:

Choose Your Eamil address:

[image]

But I want to login as `info@jegeachi.com` and it should look like a gmail acount. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add inside the tags the relevant language. Also try to add relevant code regarding the question.

Comment: Do you have a Google Apps for Web account?

Comment: If you don't have Google Apps email service..how can you login? You have to sign up for Google Apps email service... You can access your cPanel email using http://yourdomain:2095

Comment: Thanks. I just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways (in my opinion):

1. Buy a Google Apps Account, change your domain's MXs to point to Google Mail Server, login in Google Console and create your email `info@jegeachi.com`.
2. Create a free Gmail Account (`info.jegeachi@gmail.com` for example), login in Gmail, click settings

[image: Click Settings],

click POP3 and 'Other accounts' and insert your cPanel address (vps.foo.bar), your email and password when prompted

[image].

With the first way you use Gmail as mail server, in the second one you use Gmail as mail client.